# How to undo a revert in git?

Tags: git, gerrit

I need to undo a revert done in git and pushed to a remote repository. The repository is not used by anyone else. I did this with the backthought that a revert is just another commit. Thus I tried git reset and then push but it did not seem to work. Does anyone know how this can be done?

```
-> git reset --hard HEAD~1
HEAD is now at ee7abe9 <msg>
-> git push -f origin myBranch
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: done    
To 'ssh://remoteRepo'
  ! [remote rejected] mo_cache-BLACK -> mo_cache-BLACK (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://remoteRepo'
```

Comment: Can't you just revert the revert (unless you want to completely remove that revert from the branch)?

Comment: Is it a Gerrit server?

Comment: @NikolaStojiljkovic well, now I feel stupid :). I have no excuse why this would not work. Guess I did not think so far...

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira yep, it is a gerrit server. Can this be a permission issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bypassing the Gerrit review (not using refs/for/) and trying to rewrite the history (-f). I think you don't have permissions for that. It will be easier if you:

1. Go to the Gerrit web UI
2. Search the Change you want to revert
3. Click on the "Revert" button

A change will be created, just review, approve and submit it.

Comment: Well, this is probably correct. I was hoping to do this more cleanly. I did a revert on the revert. However now I will have to make 3 more revert or one commit which undo all the changes made before. I was hoping to avoid this kind of mess but you are probably right. My first guess was that it was a permission history.

Comment: I understand your concern with the "mess"... it's really nice to see the clear history but (on the other side) it's better to keep the history unchanged and to be able to know/understand how/when something was changed/reverted.

Comment: I could not agree more, if this branch was not just temporary. The history is not meant to be kept in the end. The branch is created to be able to do a black release. I wanted to keep this nice and clean and in case things like this happened I did not want to mess up the history :P

Comment: Ok. To be able to rewrite history you need to ask to Gerrit Admin to grant "force push" (-f) permission on this branch.

Comment: Right, I just figured this out. Anyway this would probably not happen any time soon, so I will have to stick with revert or asking the guy with permission. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
git push origin +myBranch
```

The `+` sign will force updating remote branch

Answer (score 0):

This can achieve in 2 ways:

- If changes pushed on git. `git checkout HEAD^^ -- .` and then `git add -A && git commit .. git push.`
- If changes are not pushed on git `git reset --hard HEAD^` (be more careful with it, though!)

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to have all the commits on the branch path unless I've pushed a password by mistake or some sensitive information. Therefore I suggest that you "revert the revert" by applying `git revert <commit id of your previous revert>` then `commit` and `push` that to the `origin`.

Comment: The problem is that under a Jenkins job there was a lot of commits done, which basically just updated the pom.xml. The Jenkins job then failed and by mistake I reverted the wrong commit. I would then want to revert the commits that was done by Jenkins (since I will need a snapshot in the pom and this was removed by Jenkins and the new snapshot was not added due to the crash). The hope was to remove this cleanly since all was mistakes to begin with (and go back to the commit I mistakenly removed).

Comment: I see. Yeah, in that case I might consider removing all commits done by Jenkins (by using force push), which I you have probably done already by following the guidelines in other answers.